# getOneToMany returns repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, entity

Executing the code below gives the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
$stock = $offerDetail->getStock();
foreach($stock as $s)
{
    ...
}
```

the stock that is returned is the class **offerDetailRepository**

this is the relation I defined in offerDetail:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OfferDetailStock", mappedBy="offerDetail", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $stock;
```

and in OfferDetailStock

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Powershop\ApplicationBundle\Entity\OfferDetail", inversedBy="stock")
*/
protected $offerDetail;
```

Some of the functions that I generated in OfferDetail:

```
public function getStock()
{
    return $this->stock;
}

public function setStock($stock)
{
    $this->stock = $stock;
}

public function addStock($stock)
{
    $this->stock[] = $stock;
}
```

And in OfferDetailStock

```
public function getOfferDetail() {
    return $this->offerDetail;
}

public function setOfferDetail($offerDetail) {
    $this->offerDetail = $offerDetail;
}
```

Does anybody have a clue? as far as my knowledge goes the relations are defined properly.
I do have to mention originally there was a ManyToMany relationship to the class Stock, I made afterwards OfferDetailStock as a table in between. I did clear the cache and updated the scheme.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter in your console:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities PowershopApplicationBundle:OfferDetail
```

It will generate the missing constructor:

> ```
> public function __construct()
> {
>     $this->stock = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot about the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In your OfferDetail entity constructor add:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->stock = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Maybe offerdetails do not have stocks and getStocks returns null.